# Date comparison Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How do I make a comparison between dates using SQlite, I tried this more failed. help: D
My Query:

```
SELECT 
        latitude, 
        longitude, 
        grupo_crime_id_grupo_crime, 
        descricao, 
        id_crime, 
        cities_id_cities, 
        time, 
        estado 
FROM crime WHERE 
        cities_id_cities='0' AND 
        time >= datetime('2013-03-28T09:30:37-03:00') 
        time <= datetime('2013-0328T09:30:37-03:00') AND 
        grupo_crime_id_grupo_crime='1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like this:

```
select * from MyTable 
where mydate >= Datetime('2000-01-01 00:00:00') 
and mydate <= Datetime('2050-01-01 23:00:59')
```